# How can I run this script by twitter?

Tags: twitter, fetch, tweets

Super unexperienced with code, however I want to learn how to fetch all the tweets off of my timeline of the users I follow using a code instead of me having to manually do it?

I found this: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-users-id-reverse-chronological

Which is perfect but i don't know how to run it lol... Any guide/youtube vid on how to use twitter codes?

Comment: Uh... that is an API. Not a script. I guess you _could_ just `curl` the endpoint (where the data comes from), but you probably want to parse the API response using something like Python or JavaScript

Comment: @cocomac Any video or article you can link me that might show me how to do that? –

Comment: There are [several code examples](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/tree/main/Reverse-Chron-Home-Timeline/OAuth1a-user) in TwitterDev GitHub - you will need to know more about how to run code in JavaScript, Python or Ruby though.